# Найти самую маленькую дробь C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно найти самую маленькую дробь в массиве. Есть такой код на генерацию случайных дробей, но он почему-то не выводит их на экран.
Заранее спасибо)

```
using System;

class program
{
    struct Drob
    {
        public int Ch { get; set; }
        public int Zn { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Drob[] d = new Drob[15];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
        {
            d[i] = new Drob
            {
                Ch = r.Next(1, 10),
                Zn = r.Next(1, 10)
            };
            Console.Write(d[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `но он почему-то не выводит их на экран` где в коде вывод на экран?

Comment: извиняюсь, не тот код.  Когда пытаюсь выводить на экран, вместо значений пишет "Program+Drob"

Comment: прикрепите тогда код вывода, иначе как понять, по каким причинам выводится что-то не то

Comment: Значит у класса дроби надо перегрузить метод ToString

Comment: @tym32167 даже примерно не представляю как это сделать

Comment: ключевые слова для гугла `перегрузить метод ToString`

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так сделайте (ни, или какой вывод вы предпочитаете):

```
class program
{
    struct Drob
    {
        public int Ch { get; set; }
        public int Zn { get; set; }
        public override string ToString(){
            return "[" + Ch + "/" + Zn + "]";
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Drob[] d = new Drob[15];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
        {
            d[i] = new Drob
            {
                Ch = r.Next(1, 10),
                Zn = r.Next(1, 10)
            };
            Console.Write(d[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Drob min = d[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < d.Length; i++)
        {
            if (min.Ch*d[i].Zn > min.Zn*d[i].Ch)
            {
                min = d[i];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Min: " + min);
    }
}
```

Comment: так вроде основной вопрос как раз в организации сравнения и был? :)

Comment: @Grundy В заголовке. В тексте вопроса жалобы на невывод. Но раз так... исправил.

Comment: ну блин, я думал будет через наименьшее общее кратное что-то :-D а тут просто перемножил крест на крест :-D

Comment: @Grundy А зачем сложно, если можно просто? :)